# Why does this hta file flash a large square before displaying the image?

Tags: html, vbscript, hta

I have the following code display an image called Test1.png

While the image itself displays correctly, when first opened a large white square flashes for a second before the image opens.

How can I get rid of this shape that flashes for a second.

**Code:**

```
<html>
    <HTA:APPLICATION ID = "oHTA"
        BORDER          = "none"
        BORDERSTYLE     = "normal"
        CAPTION         = "no"
        CONTEXTMENU     = "no"
        SYSMENU         = "no"
        NAVIGABLE       = "no"
        INNERBORDER     = "no"
        SCROLL          = "no"
        SELECTION       = "no"
        SINGLEINSTANCE  = "yes"
        WINDOWSTATE     = "normal"
        SHOWINTASKBAR   = "no"
    />
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=9">

  <style type="text/css">
    body {
        background-color: red; 
        border-color:     red; 
        margin-top:      -1px;
        margin-left:     -1px;
        margin-bottom:   -1px;
        margin-right:    -1px;
    }
  </style>

  <script language="VBScript">
      Option Explicit
      Dim width, height
      width  = 478 -1                 '''  
      height =  50 -1                 ''' 
      Sub window_onload()
          CenterWindow width, height
      End Sub
      Sub CenterWindow( widthX, heightY )
          self.ResizeTo widthX, heightY 
          self.MoveTo (screen.availWidth - widthX)/2, (screen.availHeight - heightY)/2
      End Sub
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <img src="Test1.png"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's the original HTA window before it's being resized and moved. I'm not sure you can get rid of it entirely. I'd try putting `ResizeTo()` and `MoveTo()` directly into `window_onload()`.

Comment: @Teemu can you please show what you mean in a response, I would really appreciate it and mark it as the answer

Answer (score 2):

When you know the size and place of the HTA window beforehand, take the resizing and repositioning out of `window.onload`, and make them the first action in the script, and, move `<hta>` tag after reposition/resizing within the head. This works, since the window is invisible untill all the code placed before `<hta>` is executed.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=9">
        <style type="text/css">
            body {
                background-color: red; 
                border-color:     red; 
                margin-top:      -1px;
                margin-left:     -1px;
                margin-bottom:   -1px;
                margin-right:    -1px;
           }
       </style>    
       <script language="VBScript">
           Option Explicit
           Dim width, height
           width  = 478 -1                 '''  
           height =  50 -1                 ''' 
           self.ResizeTo width, height 
           self.MoveTo (screen.availWidth - width)/2, (screen.availHeight - height)/2
      </script>
      <HTA:APPLICATION ID = "oHTA"
          BORDER          = "none"
          BORDERSTYLE     = "normal"
          CAPTION         = "no"
          CONTEXTMENU     = "no"
          SYSMENU         = "no"
          NAVIGABLE       = "no"
          INNERBORDER     = "no"
          SCROLL          = "no"
          SELECTION       = "no"
          SINGLEINSTANCE  = "yes"
          WINDOWSTATE     = "normal"
          SHOWINTASKBAR   = "no"
     />
</head>
```